# AWS Cognito how to authenticate users within many UserPools

Tags: amazon-cognito

I've created AWS Cognito UserPool, an client application on top of it and I can auth users via OIDC, everything works as expected.

My use case is a bit more complex: I want to have many user pools and one application. By that, I want to separate users but when somebody tries to login, expected scenario is to loop each userpool and to determine if such user exist.

So far I've managed to put many userpools into one identity ppol, but I have no clue how to auth against such pool in my use case (external application, preferably OIDC client).

Answer (score 0):

In the back-end of your code, you could have `try-catch` blocks for the InititateAuth API, to check if the user exists for that particular App Client ID(which is connected to a User Pool ID). However, there might be edge cases in which the same User Name and Password could be valid for multiple User Pools. Cognito does not offer any native API for this use-case, and a manual try-catch seems like an only plausible solution.

An Identity Pool would not help you out with this use-case, since it a technology designed for Authorization, and not for Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually have a solution, I'll use different subdomains for each UserPool and by the subdomain I'll know against which UserPool to try authentication. It's just too much work over Cognito APIs as I'll need to create a pool, create a client app, get ID and secret, configure domain for OIDC, configure subdomain mapping etc. I was hoping there is more native way to achieve this.